# You have two ASP.NET projects. One contains a copy of the other's dll, and a reference to it. Can you run the projects on two different servers?

Tags: asp.net

My question is about the necessary proximity of a dll to the project from which it was created. If you have two ASP.NET projects, and you copy the dll created by one of them, into the other project, (for example, putting it in a library folder), and then add a reference to that copy so it can be used, do the two projects need to run on the same server?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can definitely do this. You have to ensure that the referenced dll files are getting copied over. And as they are separate applications, you can easily deploy them on separate servers. Though I am not entirely sure why do you need to add a reference of ASP.NET project to another ASP.NET project. You might be able to achieve sharing of code by creating separate class library project and referring that.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much for giving me a clear answer. The referenced one contains a lot of methods which are used by many other projects, so they each contain a reference to its dll. But almost all of them live on the same server as that project, and I wasn't sure if the same thing could be done in the few that live elsewhere. Thank you!

Comment: @OnwardsAndUpwards I think he is saying "why can't you separate the shared functionality into be a pure library?".  that would be better for sure.

Comment: @OnwardsAndUpwards Yes as long ass all required dll files are deployed, it would be usable. If there is a common class library project containing the methods. And then the 2 separate apps reference that project, it is totally fine. Hope I understood your scenario.

Comment: I agree that a library seems like the sensible option, but I have to take a light touch / minimal expense approach with this task, and as it's already set up to work in this way through loads of projects, I'm going to keep it as it is, if possible. Many thanks guys!